# how to get utf8 encoded html content

Tags: python, mysql, ascii, encode

I have next code

```
# __author__ = 'Vahagn'
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import BeautifulSoup
import requests
     req = requests.get(u"http://knowledge.allbest.ru/chemistry/3c0a65635a3ad68b5c53b88421306c27.html")
     s2 = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(req.content).find('p',{'class':'text'}).text
     print(s2+'\n')
```

Where I pring s2, to console or file writed

```
Õèìè÷åñêèå ñâîéñòâà. Ìèíåðàëû. Ìåäíûå ñïëàâû. Ìàðêè ìåäíûõ ñïëàâîâ. Ìåäíî-öèíêîâûå ñïëàâû. Ëàòóíè. Îëîâÿííûå áðîíçû. Àëþìèíèåâûå áðîíçû. Êðåìíèñòûå áðîíçû. Áåðèëëèåâûå áðîíçû. Ìåäü â ïðîìûøëåííîñòè. Ìåäü â æèçíè ðàñòåíèé è æèâîòíûõ.
```

But need

```
Химические свойства. Минералы. Медные сплавы. Марки медных сплавов. Медно-цинковые сплавы. Латуни. Оловянные бронзы. Алюминиевые бронзы. Кремнистые бронзы. Бериллиевые бронзы. Медь в промышленности. Медь в жизни растений и животных.
```

Please help, how I can fix it, for after this text (s2) write to mysql. Thank you.

Comment: You should really be using beautifulSoup4

Comment: It works fine for me, it is your system encoding that is the problem. Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: where are you running the code? what does `req.encoding` output?

Comment: req.encoding -> windows - 1251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to decode:

```
s2 = BeautifulSoup(req.content.decode("windows-1251")).find('p',{'class':'text'}).tex‌​t 


In [72]: s2 = BeautifulSoup(req.content).find('p',{'class':'text'}).text
In [73]: s2
Out[73]: 'Õèìè÷åñêèå ñâîéñòâà. Ìèíåðàëû. Ìåäíûå ñïëàâû. Ìàðêè ìåäíûõ ñïëàâîâ. Ìåäíî-öèíêîâûå ñïëàâû. Ëàòóíè. Îëîâÿííûå áðîíçû. Àëþìèíèåâûå áðîíçû. Êðåìíèñòûå áðîíçû. Áåðèëëèåâûå áðîíçû. Ìåäü â ïðîìûøëåííîñòè. Ìåäü â æèçíè ðàñòåíèé è æèâîòíûõ.'

In [74]: s2 = BeautifulSoup(req.content.decode("windows-1251")).find('p',{'class':'text'}).text    
In [75]: s2
Out[75]: 'Химические свойства. Минералы. Медные сплавы. Марки медных сплавов. Медно-цинковые сплавы. Латуни. Оловянные бронзы. Алюминиевые бронзы. Кремнистые бронзы. Бериллиевые бронзы. Медь в промышленности. Медь в жизни растений и животных.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the HTML and the response headers, the web server doesn't send you the encoding of the data. That means Python must make a guess. I think it will use your default encoding (whatever your OS uses).

Try to convert `req.content` into `unicode` with different encodings until you find one that produces the correct output:

```
content = unicode(req.content, encoding)
```

Try `utf-8` and `iso-latin-1` as encodings or some common encodings used in Russia.

Comment: s2 = unicode(s2, encoding='utf-8')
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

Comment: Seems like `s2` is already a kind of Unicode string but it was probably garbled. Try `s2 = s.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')` Or look at the `requests` modules if you can override/specify the encoding of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode it before print it out. Like this:

```
import BeautifulSoup
import requests
     req = requests.get(u"http://knowledge.allbest.ru/chemistry/3c0a65635a3ad68b5c53b88421306c27.html")
     s2 = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(req.content).find('p',{'class':'text'}).text
     s2 = s2.encode('utf-8')
     print(s2+'\n')
```

Comment: s2 = unicode(s2, encoding='utf-8') TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported

Comment: I try this way - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)